# How to see if site on IIS running with https certificate

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, https

Say I got two servers. One running with a https certificate and the other isn't.
The user that visit one of my sites types http. If that sites pointing to the server with https certificate then I want to redirect the user/rewrite the url.

There is only one thing that remains. How do I check if my site got the certificate? Or if the binding is https?

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    var variableToSeeIfIISSiteRunningOnCertificate = true;
    if (variableToSeeIfIISSiteRunningOnCertificate && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && path.ToLower().Contains("loginpage.aspx"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public bool HasValidCertificate(url){
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
    X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
    X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
    string cn = cert2.GetIssuerName();
    string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
    string cpub = cert2.GetPublicKeyString();

    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cn) && cedate > DateTime.Now && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpub);
}
```

not tested but should give some insight on how to do it.